# Как вывести изображения в селекте?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, плагин

Как сделать селект с миниатюрами (маленькими изображениями) вместо текста? Попробовал несколько плагинов типа *jquery-form-styler* или *nice-select*, ни в том, ни в другом изображения не отображаются, подскажите чем всё-таки можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Из готовых плагинов могу посоветовать [**Chosen**](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) + [**Image Select**](https://github.com/websemantics/Image-Select).

Код из туториала:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".my-select").chosen();
});
```

```html
<select class="my-select">
  <option data-img-src="img/adnan.png">Adnan Sagar</option>
  <option data-img-src="img/rena.png">Rena Cugelman</option>
  <option data-img-src="img/tavis.png">Tavis Lochhead</option>
  <option data-img-src="img/brian.png" selected="selected">Brain Cugelman</option>
</select>
```

В результате, насколько я помню, внутри опции для выбора создается изображение с урлом, который указан в `data-img-src`.

Comment: @VostokSisters добавление сюда jquery не сделает сниппет рабочим, тут придется подключать еще много чего остального, потому я и не вставлял его намеренно.